# Export Excel from SQL Server using linked server

Tags: sql-server, excel

I'm exporting a table from SQL server to Excel using sp_addlinkedserver

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver @MYTABLE,
                        @srvproduct='',
                        @provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                        @datasrc= @MYFILENAME,
                        @provstr = 'Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES'

....


exec sp_dropserver @MYTABLENAME, 'droplogins'
```

And it works as expected

But the XLSX file keeps opened until the stored procedure returns

After exporting the table I was supposed to email it as a attachment to the customer, but as the file is open, sending the email fails

I've tested it serveral times, and it is 100% sure that the file is closed only after the procedure ends, dropserver is not enough to close it

Does someone have a clue on how to close the file?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can enclose this proc into another proc that sends the email, thus this proc will end and release the file?

Or you could drop the server before you email?

Comment: The proc that exports the table is called by a "main" proc, and it ends normally. The next step is to send the file, but the file is only closed when the topmost proc ends. I DO call sp_dropserver before sending the email.